# How to get a SPList's default edit SPForm programatically?

Tags: splist

I have created a new edit form for my SPList via Sharepoint Designer and haven't deleted the old ones. I know how to get all the forms, but how to distinguish default forms from the rest?

I can see in Sharepoint Designer which one is set to default, but can I get this information programatically?

My current function gets all the forms and distuingishes only by PAGETYPE. What can I improve?

```
public static string getFormName(string listName, PAGETYPE formType)
{
   SPFormCollection forms = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[listName].Forms;
   foreach (SPForm form in forms)
   {
      // todo: how to choose default form
   }
   return formName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working on something else I accidently found an answer to this one.
When I have an SPList in code, like this:

```
SPList myList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[listName];
```

I can get default forms from SPList properties:

```
string defaultEditForm    = myList.DefaultEditFormUrl;
string defaultDisplayForm = myList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl;
string defaultNewForm     = myList.DefaultNewFormUrl;
```

I hope this will come in handy for someone in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

SPForm.Type == PAGETYPE.PAGE_EDITFORM

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem. Already tried that. Let's say I have two edit forms assigned to one list. If I used your condition to get the number of all edit forms, then I would get two. Because both of them will return true for (SPForm.Type == PAGETYPE.PAGE_EDITFORM). But how to tell which one is set to default?